# Using IN with other conditions in Redbean

Tags: php, sql, redbean

I am trying to find some beans by using "IN" as well as "=". I am currently using this code:

```
$ids = array(1,2,3,4);
$user = 1;

$things = R::find(
  'thing', 
  'id IN ('.R::genSlots($ids).') AND user = ?',
  array(
    $ids,
    $user
  )
);
```

This gives me some errors:

> PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in rb.php on line 217
>
> Fatal error:  Uncaught [HY093] - SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens thrown in rb.php on line 267

If I run this code with one item in $id I only get the notice but either way I get no results.

I'm assuming it's trying to treat $id as a single variable. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure `R::genSlots()` accepts an array?

Comment: Isn't that what it's for?

Comment: Why not simply use implode(',', $ids) instead of R::genSlots ?

Comment: @OIS I could do but but parameterised queries are generally a better idea.

Comment: What you want is implode(',', array_fill(0,count($ids),'?')

Comment: Yeah that's done. Feels kind of hacky in this context though. If there's a function for doing this in Redbean, why can't I use it?

Comment: I have no knowledge of Redbean sorry. Maybe someone else has a better understanding of how to do this with your original method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

don't add the $ids to the array, merge the two into one array, otherwise this will end up as a nested array.